# SQL JOIN avoid duplicate in column value

Tags: sql, join, view, duplicates

I'm trying to create a view with join on a specific column. When duplicates on the joining column exist in 1 of the tables, the join duplicates the values on the opposite table where there is no duplicates. I need to show the values but only match it once, if a second match is found, the non-duplicated table should show null. Is it possible?

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT A.id as id_a, B.id as id_b   
FROM table1 A
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 B ON  A.columnX = B.columnX --- the duplicate is in this column
```

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, naturally. You can do a `left join`, like this:

```
select A.id as id_a, B.id as id_B, A.columnX
from table2 B
left join table1 A
on (A.columnX = B.columnX) and
(not exists (select 1
             from table2 B2
             where B2.columnX = B.columnX and B2.id < B.id)
)
```

Basically, we added the non existence of a match with a smaller `id` into the `on` clause

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to do this!  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  This is true of queries and views as well.  In fact, even if you include an `ORDER BY` in your view, the results are not guaranteed to be returned in any particular order.

The issue is that interpreting your results requires following the ordering of the rows.  The id value for the `NULL` depends on whatever id is "above" it, but you cannot control that.

Worse, you are using a `FULL JOIN`, so you might get `NULL` values from the `JOIN` itself.

What you want to do is not recommended at all!

Comment: What would be the recommended way to do it?

Comment: @aruydzi1 . . . Include the full information on each row.

Comment: That would not be possible since each id is coming from a different system and there might be values that exist only in 1 system